# HR tag renders white pixel

Tags: html, css

In IE8 and mozilla 3.5 theres an white pixel to the right. How can i get rid of that? Seting background-color changes nothing. neither does width.

```
hr {
 border-top: 1px solid #111;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
```

This is how it looks right now

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to the CSS fixes it (I also noticed a white pixel on the left side, though smaller than the right):

```
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
```